# MVC Link Creation

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

Using this route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "PartListRoute",
        "Products/PartList/{Manufacturer}/{Product}/{PartNumber}",
        new { controller = "PartList", action = "Index", Manufacturer = UrlParameter.Optional, Product = UrlParameter.Optional, PartNumber = "" }
    );
```

I am attempting to create a link going from /Products/PartList to /Products/PartList/Manufacturer1 based on a list of manufacturers pulled from a database.  mfr.Name is the name of the manufacturer.

The route should lead to urls like the following

- /Products/PartList/
- /Products/PartList/Manufacturer1/
- /Products/PartList/Manuracturer3/Product1/
- /Products/PartList/Manuracturer2/Product4/DN-438

The closest I've come is

```
@Html.RouteLink(mfr.Name, "PartListRoute", new { Manufacturer = mfr.Name} )
```

Which puts the manufacturer name in the text, but does not add it to the URL.  I get the feeling I'm assuming something about routes and links that isn't true.

Is there actually way to use the Route to generate a new Link in the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this question, I finally stumbled across this article, indicating there's a bug when you have consecutive optional URL parameters.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

I won't claim I fully understand the explanation, but creating additional routes all pointing back to the original controller seems to have fixed the problem:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "PartListRoute",
            "Products/PartList/{Manufacturer}",
            new { controller = "PartList", action = "Index", Manufacturer = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "PartListRoute2",
            "Products/PartList/{Manufacturer}/{Product}",
            new { controller = "PartList", action = "Index", Manufacturer = UrlParameter.Optional, Product = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "PartListRoute3",
            "Products/PartList/{Manufacturer}/{Product}/{PartNumber}",
            new { controller = "PartList", action = "Index", Manufacturer = UrlParameter.Optional, Product = UrlParameter.Optional, PartNumber = "" }
        );
```